# Display Form Input PHP

Tags: php, echo

I am sending a form over PHP and displaying the results on a new page. I would like to display the dates inputted by the user on this new page so that they have a reminder of what date they entered. I have tried the following which did not work:

```
echo "$start"
```

Here is my code for the front-end form:

```
<form action="availability" method="get">
<div id="cin">Check-In Date: <input type="text" id="start" name="start"></div>
<div id="cout">Check-Out Date: <input type="text" id="end" name="end"></div>

<div id="csubmit"><input type="submit"></div>
</form>
```

'Start' being the field i'm trying to pull. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_GET['start']
```

if it's `method="get"`, otherwise

```
$_POST['start']
```

or if you're lazy

```
$_REQUEST['start']
```

which is both post and get (in some specific order ;o)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, unfortunately I get the following response: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ‘,’ or ‘;’

Comment: Resolved! I was missed the ';' off the end. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using GET to send the data you have to `echo $_GET["start"];`. If you are going to use POST you can `echo $_POST["start"];`

Anyway, I suggest you to search some tutorials on google and learn the basics of PHP programming. You will find so many useful explanations...

Comment: Argh; I had stupidly missed the ';' of the end. That was my problem. Dumb moment - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First off, your action does not have the file extension. and you need to use the `$_GET['start'];` to get your values on the page your action is pointed to. should be like below.

FORM PAGE:

```
<form action="availability.php" method="get">
    <div id="cin">Check-In Date: <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    </div>
    <div id="cout">Check-Out Date: <input type="text" id="end" name="end">
    </div>

    <div id="csubmit"><input type="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Action Page: availability.php

```
$_GET['start'];
echo $start;
```

Comment: It doesn't need the file extension - I am using Wordpress and it works fine without it.

Comment: @IVCatalina ah, my bad.